# Problems Installing Qt SDK on Mac OS X Lion

Tags: qt, qt4, installation

I've just upgraded to OS X Lion and am I trying to install Qt SDK. I've installed Qt 4.7.3 through [homebrew](https://brew.sh/), and am trying to get [Qt SDK 1.1.1](http://qt.nokia.com/downloads/%5C) running my machine.

I downloaded the installer from the nokia Qt site, and run it. However, during the installation, a strange series of errors appeared:

[image: First Qt Install Error Message]

I clicked "Retry" a few times to no avail, so hit "Ignore", as "Cancel" just quits the installer.

[image: Second Qt Install Error Message]

Again, clicked "Retry".

[image: Third Qt Install Error Message]

Finally, clicked "Retry" again, and the installation completed.

However, there's obviously something faulty, because when I try to run Qt Creator, I am greeted with the following window:

[image]

As one can see, the Qt Designer tab on the right, as well as the Projects tab are greyed out. I tried running the installer again, and the same exact errors pop up. I tried googling a solution (looking for errors involving harmattan-postinstall.sh) and nothing came up.

Has anyone else encountered these problems? Does anyone know of a solution?

Comment: An updated version of the QtSDK is available which might solve the problem. I was able to install the QtSDK fine on Lion and using homebrew. The fact that the Qt Designer tab is grayed out is unrelated to the error you are having, you just have to install it. To install it just select "SDK Maintenance Tool" in your QtSDK directory and then Select "Package Manager" and continue. You should be able select and install additional tools such as Qt Designer as well as other things like examples. Hope this helps.

Comment: This did the trick.Thanks! Feel free to submit this as an answer and I'll mark it as an answer. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer from the user, cwadding:

> An updated version of the QtSDK is available which might solve the
>   problem. I was able to install the QtSDK fine on Lion and using
>   homebrew. The fact that the Qt Designer tab is grayed out is unrelated
>   to the error you are having, you just have to install it. To install
>   it just select "SDK Maintenance Tool" in your QtSDK directory and then
>   Select "Package Manager" and continue. You should be able select and
>   install additional tools such as Qt Designer as well as other things
>   like examples. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I should have just submitted it as an answer. I would appreciate an upvote on my comment at least.

Answer (score 8):

All you need to do is install GCC - that comes with Xcode !
I had the same issues Lion, I installed gcc, and reinstalled QT... things went smooth.
to double check if you have the same issues, use " which gcc" and see if you have gcc.

- To install gcc, go to Xcode->Preference->Downloads and click install button besides "Command line tools".

Comment: This solved it for me. App Store Xcode doesn't install command line utilities by default anymore.